# Retrieve next records from Database based on previous selection by user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using SQL server and I have the following 2 database tables:

[Question_Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbr8V.png)

[Questionnaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65uuy.png)

Now I want questions to be displayed from DB along with answers.
But the next question to be displayed will depend on previous question's answer.

Suppose for Q1 the user selects YES -> Q2 will appear next.

But if the user selects NO -> Q3 would appear.

Below is my code:

```
public partial class Recommendation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int QuesIndex = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RecommendationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        PopulateDataTable();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Label2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();
                HiddenField2.Value = dt.Rows[QuesIndex]["Question_ID"].ToString();
                HiddenField1.Value ="1";
            }
            BindList();
            //QuesIndex++;
        }
        if (Request.Form["HiddenField1"] != null)

            rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["HiddenField1"].ToString());

        if (rowIndex == dt.Rows.Count && rowIndex != 0)
        {
            rowIndex = 0;
            HiddenField1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(0).ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void BindList()
    {
        DataSet DS1 = new DataSet();

        string command = "Select ID, Answers from Question_Answer where Ques_ID = '" + HiddenField2.Value + "'";
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ques_ID", Ques_ID);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command, con);        
        dataAdaptor.Fill(DS1);
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = DS1;
        RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Answers";
        RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    }

     private void PopulateDataTable()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Question_ID, Question from Questionnaire", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sDA.Fill(ds, "Questionnaire");                      
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Label2.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Question"].ToString();
            HiddenField2.Value = dt.Rows[QuesIndex ["Question_ID"].ToString();
            rowIndex++;
            QuesIndex++;
            HiddenField1.Value = rowIndex.ToString();
        }
        Session["QnA"] = HiddenField2.Value;      
      }
```

This code is just fetching Questions 1 by 1 from Db Questionnaire. But I want the next question to appear based on the user's previous answer.

How can I do that?

Comment: By looking at the code, you are not maintaining the association between the response answer and what is the next question that is linked to that response answer. If you are newly developing this app, please come out from asp.net web forms and ADO.NET or if it is an old code base that you are extending...i pray to the god to give you all strength,courage and patience :-)

Comment: @Thangadurai That is what i want to know how to do the association b/w response answer and the next question.

Comment: Well first you need to store this association somewhere. How variable / flexible does it need to be? The trivial solution is to just hard code it in your code. The more flexible solution is to store it in a database in some kind of linked list.

Comment: @NIck : You can refer to the Database Question_Answer snapshot i have attached above : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbr8V.png
 That table contains the associations for the answer id's selected.

Comment: Oh I didn’t see that. Well I guess you use that to decide which page to redirect to. I agree that you shouldn’t be developing new work in web forms. I wouldn’t even know how to redirect in webforms.

Comment: Using web forms is the requirement.

Actually its kind of a survey questionnaires. Next question also have to be displayed in that same label not redirect to next page.

I am unable to get the next question id from Db on button click

Comment: I have figured it out. Putting a select querry in the Button_Click event did the trick.
select * from Questionnaire where Question_ID =(select Nxt_Ques_ID from Question_Answer where ID = '" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue + "')
Thanks guys for your help.
This topic can be closed.